# Get localhost:8080 instead of my_ip_address:8080 in wsdl2java

Tags: web-services, maven-plugin, axis, wsdl2java

I am using **axistools-maven-plugin**

This is my xml content.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
    <urls>
       <url>http://localhost:8080/link/to/webservice?wsdl</url>
    </urls>
    <packageSpace>my.package</packageSpace>
    <serverSide>true</serverSide>
    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
       <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I ***get*** the generated output as:

```
http://my_ip_address:8080/link/to/webservice
```

I ***want*** the generated output as:

```
http://localhost:8080/link/to/webservice
     OR
http://127.0.0.1:8080/link/to/webservice
```

Because **http://my_ip_address:8080/link/to/webservice** (which I think) will try to get connection from network. I want to connect locally.

Please help..

**UPDATE:**

It works in Windows XP but not in Linux (CentOS). Sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since I got no answers, I think I found my own answer.

I had to do a work around on it. Here is the process.

1. I download the wsdl file using the target machine itself.
2. Change the port address.

   ```
   <service name="serviceName">
     <port name="servicePort" binding="tns:soapBinding">
       <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/link/to/webservice"/>
     </port>
   </service>
   ```
3. Use that wsdl file in my development machine.